# std::array as element type of another standard container?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-c++-2015

There doesn't seem to be any rule against it, and the error I get with

```
std::vector< std::array<int,8> > output;
output.resize (8);
```

is `C2036   'std::array<int,0x08> *': unknown size`

which doesn't make sense.  The code inside `<vector>` is advancing the internal `end` pointer, which is used (as is the computed size of the extension) elsewhere as well.  The size of a `struct{int x[8];}` is certainly "known".

What's going on here?

---

Hmm, since it's not just a simple typo or somesuch, and seems to work OK when others try it (and the sample someone else wrote worked for me!) I pared down the source file until nothing was left but the offending statements and it still fails.  Here is the entire file.  Precompiled headers is turned off.

```
//#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

#include <vector>
    
int main()
{

    std::vector< std::array<int,8> > output;
    output.resize (16);

}
```

I'm building using x64, release build.

---

## Figured it out:

It's not a missing #include for `vector`, but for `array`!
It is apparently forward-declared in other headers but is incomplete.

Comment: The error message says the size of the pointer is unknown - which, of course, doesn't make sense either.

Comment: can you provide some more code to better understand context? have you added "#include <array>" line?

Comment: Please copy-paste the exact file (with the `#include`s) that you gave to the compiler.

Comment: Is it still necessary in vs2015 to specify the c++11 standard?

Comment: Probably a bug in MSVC.

Comment: without a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details about the compiler, we cannot help, and your post is liable to be closed.

Comment: @zenith Works for me with MSVC2015 (14.0.23107.0). I used the code from `Valery Shevchuk`'s example

Comment: @JDługosz I get the same error when I remove the include for `<array>`. Are you sure that your includes are correct?

Comment: If `<array>` was not *explicitly* `#include`d, the code should still not fail like that, but either compile fine (if `<array>` was *implicitly* `#include`d) or fail with a error message about unknown type/template `std::array<>`. The behaviour you reported seems at least odd; I wonder whether it is standard compliant.

Comment: I recall from the Boost containers that being able to use types as container elements before they have been completely defined is a purposeful improvement.  Some other header must declare but not define array, perhaps to pacify other code that's benign if not actually used.  Delaying the need for the full definition of the type is intentional in writing the templates.  I realize that "size unknown" points to that now; A more specific error message would be nicer, e.g. "template array is only a placeholder and the size is needed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

everything seems to be ok with this code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::vector< std::array<int,8> > output;
    output.resize(8);
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone test example](http://ideone.com/3S1wbv)

Have you added the `#include <array>` line?

Comment: Yes, it has the proper includes... it chokes inside the <vector> header file template function for resize().

Comment: @JDługosz, can you provide more code to better understand error context? And also, full compiler error output.

Comment: @JDługosz what do you mean by "it chokes inside the <vector> header file template function for resize()."? What are the error messages thatyou are getting?

Comment: I wonder what he's going to do now.

Comment: @RyanFung, `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1145): error C2036: 'std::array<int,0x08> *': unknown size` is inside the template code for `vector::resize`, if you are still interested.